# What is the meaning of v0 in tcm id like tcm:163-34568-v0?

Tags: core-service

I create a multimedia component by core service and print it's tcm id I found printed tcm Id like  tcm:163-34568-v0 but when I go sdl gui I found that there tcm showing like  tcm:163-34568

what is the mean of -v0 in tcm Id how I remove the -v0 from the tcm Id .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In -V{n}, {n} simply represents the version of the item. like "-V24" is 24th version.

As Andrey answered below, V0 is called dynamic version and this represent the checked out version.

Answer (score 8):

The `v0` is called dynamic version. It means that this is the version of checked out item. For example you have a component with Id tcm:x-xx - this means this is the latest checked in version of your component. It's the same as tcm:x-xx-v(last major version number). If you will check it out, tcm:x-xx will still point to the latest checked in version and there will be a new version created - tcm:x-xx-v0 - this is the dynamic version. It contains all the changes made while item is checked out. When item get's checked in, tcm:x-xx-v0 becomes the next version of item and `-v0` is removed. So in your case, `-v0` means that item is checked out and you have a dynamic version in your hands.

Keep in mind that not everyone can read dynamic version, safe bet is user who checked item out or user who is assignee in current workflow activity.

Answer (score 2):

"v0" is the version, with the zero indicating that it's the *current* version of the Component.

As far as I know, there's no built-in way to retrieve the ID without the version; however, it's simple enough to produce:

```
var version = string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}", tcmId.PublicationId, tcmId.ItemId);
```

Or with an extension method:

```
public static string WithoutVersion(this TcmUri tcmId)
{
    if (tcmId.ItemType == ItemType.Component)
    {
        return string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}", tcmId.PublicationId, tcmId.ItemId);
    }

    return string.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}-{0}",
        tcmId.PublicationId, tcmId.ItemId, (int)tcmId.ItemType);
}
```

Comment: Nice method, but you can simply use `TcmUri.GetVersionlessUri()`

Comment: @BartKoopman That'll be why I couldn't see a property for it in the docs, then.